# Does a What If…? character appear in Spider-Man: No Way Home 2nd Post-credit scene/content?

Tags: marvel, marvel-cinematic-universe, marvel-what-if-2021, spider-man-no-way-home

Warning: the basis of this question is a spoiler for *Spider-Man: No Way Home*, and I’ve tried to obscure that spoiler as best as possible. Don’t proceed unless you want to be spoiled.

In *Spider-Man: No Way Home* (2021), there is a character who appears in the second end credits scene who looks an awful lot like a slightly modified/darker…

> Doctor Strange.

This character looks like they may have more in common with

> *What If…?*’s Doctor Strange Supreme — an alternate universe version of Doctor Strange who debuted in S1E4, “What if Doctor Strange Lost His Heart Instead of His Hands,” and who returned for the final episode of S1.

Is that:

> *What If…?’s* Doctor Strange Supreme

who appears in *Spider-Man: No Way Home* second post-credit scene?

---

Note that this question is not about any future work like *Doctor Strange in the Multiverse of Madness*, but rather the existing works of the fully completed *What If...?* Season 1, and *Spider-Man: No Way Home*.

Also, whether that post-credit scene doubles as an out-of-universe film trailer is irrelevant to the question or it’s answer.

Comment: Quite possibly, but it's probably a bit too early to be able to find confirmation of that from an official source. That end-credits 'scene' is really a trailer for _Doctor Strange in the Multiverse of Madness_, which isn't due for release until May 2022, over four months from now.

Comment: Reopened. Whilst the answer may become clearer down the line I see no reason why this can't be answered now. There may potentially be out of universe material, like interviews, on this or the character may look so similar that an answer based purely on looks could be acceptable even if weak. Lastly, we don't know is a perfectly acceptable answer.

Comment: Thank you. Those were all my thoughts, particularly interviews with film’s creative people, or some program or official movie guide, or web content, as well in asking.

Comment: The question title is a bit misleading as the character appears in the trailer for Multiverse Of Madness and is not actually in No Way Home and I don't think that trailer qualified as end-credit scenes for NWH.

Comment: @user96551 Perhaps a simple test may be whether the material was included on the studio’s NWH theatrical release print and were cinemas required to play the NWH print as they received it, or could they modify or excise what you suggest might be content separate from the film.

Comment: @SillybutTrue: By that logic, if, in the future, they show a trailer of "The Little Mermaid" after the "Black Panther: Wakanda Forever" movie (possible since both are Disney properties), would you consider Sebastian a part of the MCU ? I mentioned the change above because in the future, the MOM trailer is going to drop separately and this question can become more relevant to people who are searching then.

Comment: @usee96551 If Disney had plans to integrate the Little Mermaid into MCU, then inclusion of Little Mermaid content at the end of Black Panther: Wakanda Forever uniting Sebastian with Black Panther: Wakanda Forever characters would likely constitute a planned creative choice for the Black Panther: Wakanda Forever film, and in which case I _would_ consider Sebastian a part of the MCU, and I may likely ask Little Mermaid & MCU experts of a Little Mermaid / MCU expert fantasy/sci-go website that very question .

Comment: With the multiverse we can never be sure if it is the exact same version until we have more then a trailer to go off of.   It is definitely a similar character to the one in what if but till we see more then a trailer

Comment: @TheLethalCarrot: I understand your point but I disagree. We know that people, in particular at Marvel, lie in interviews (Charlie Cox: "I am not in NWH") and trailers are edited to be misleading (Doctor Strange's discussion with Wong). A "We don't know" answer here would also render the Future Work policy quite moot.

Comment: @Taladris The future works close reason is for questions asking about information for future works. Just because something might become clearer or more obvious in a future work doesn't mean it isn't answerable now. This can very much be answered now. However, since the community has re-closed it I'll leave it alone even if I personally disagree. SillybutTrue feel free to ask on meta if this should have been closed if you want.

Comment: Should be reopened.

Comment: Instead of Meta resolution at this time, I’m holding out hope there is a secret Tug-of-War hat which meets conditions of “reopened a question, which you edited, after you have already reopened and edited the same question.” Or even a Generational War secret hat: “reopen a question three times.”

Comment: Now that it is clear that the second post credits scene was indeed the trailer for **Dr. Strange: Multiverse of Madness**, this question could fall under future works

Comment: Why can’t it be _both_ a post-credit scene of NWH as well as a trailer for DS:IMoM, and even if it is both why does DS:IMoM count more than NWH for a question about NWH’s scenes? Also technically, the “trailer” (Marvel’s official teaser) https://youtu.be/Rt_UqUm38BI is different than what was run as post-credit scene of NWH, so they didn’t just run the trailer at the end of the movie. The NWH content appears to be a specifically edited version only appearing thus far with NWH.

Comment: I've just watched the film today, and it's not the same character.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to ScreenRant:

> "Meanwhile, it also shows a first look at the return of Mordo, who left the Masters of the Mystic Arts at the end of the first film, **and confirms an appearance of Evil Strange aka Strange Supreme**, seemingly the same character introduced in Marvel's *What If...?* animated series."
>
> <sup>[ScreenRant](https://screenrant.com/doctor-strange-2-multiverse-madness-movie-trailer-mordo/); emphasis added</sup>

Collider has the following to say about it:

> "And she isn't the only magician that Strange (Benedict Cumberbatch) is gonna have to face off against: **Evil Doctor Strange, last seen in Marvel's *What If...?*, concludes the trailer with a sinister smirk.**"
>
> <sup>[Collider](https://collider.com/doctor-strange-2-trailer-in-the-multiverse-of-madness/); emphasis added</sup>

**As of now, there is no official word on it.** However, IGN does say that the trailer "confirms Evil Strange", and IGN is known for being close with Marvel and Disney for trailer reveals, such as the first *No Way Home* trailer.

Comment: Kindly update the answer since its wrong and still the accepted one', @F1crazy's answer is correct

Answer (score 7):

With *Doctor Strange in the Multiverse of Madness* having been released, we can now confirm that **no**, this is not the same character featured in *What If?*.

The version of Doctor Strange seen in *Multiverse of Madness* is known as Sinister Strange. His backstory is similar to that of Strange Supreme - he tried to use the Darkhold to save his universe, but failed - but instead of realising the error of his ways, he

> began dreamwalking into his multiversal selves and forcing them to commit suicide, believing that, since none of them were able to remain with Christine either, he is putting them all out of their misery. MCU Strange eventually defeats him by blasting him out of the window of his ruined Sanctum Sanctorum, causing him to fall onto a fence and be fatally impaled.

To make things even more confusing, the film also contains a Strange variant named "Supreme Strange", who bears *even less* of a resemblance to "Strange Supreme".

Answer (score -6):

> Yes that is the same Doctor out of *What if* the monster we saw is the one in the first episode with Cp. Carter.

Comment: How do you know _for sure_ that it's the same version of that character? Some variants of the same character in the MCU look near-identical, so visual similarity isn't a sufficient indicator.

Comment: It must the same guy! Even in a Prism of Endless Possibility™©, how could there be _two_ evil wizards?!?!?

Comment: With that said, that’s totes Shuma-Gorath, and if he/she/they dies in _Multiverse of Madness_ I will be _so_ grumpy. Protect Cal at all costs!

Comment: Things don’t bode well for Shummy. Savage Strange offed him in Savage Avengers this past summer. That’s not normally ado about anything, except that maybe killing Shuma might just be a thing on Marvel peoples’ minds.